# Why won't `date` accept it's own default output?

Tags: linux, command-line, date

On my system right now by default `date` outputs:

```
$ date
Fri 29 Jan 22:04:26 GMT 2016
```

However if I try to feed dates of this format back into `date` it results in "invalid date":

```
$ date -d "$(date)"
date: invalid date ‘Fri 29 Jan 22:06:14 GMT 2016’
```

I realise that I can manually choose a format that `date` will understand:

```
$ date -d "@$(date +%s)"
Fri 29 Jan 22:08:03 GMT 2016
```

But I am interested in why it is outputting a format that it won't accept back in.

Comment: Works for me with the `date` from coreutils 8.4. Maybe your `date` is buggy, or some other implementation.

Comment: I apparently have version 8.24, does yours output the same format as mine by default?

Comment: Same format. Works for me also on vanilla builds of coreutils 8.24 and 8.25. Maybe your Linux distro added some patches that change this behavior.

Comment: I'm using Arch.

Comment: I don't know what Arch does, but it should be pretty straightforward to download and build coreutils yourself and see if a vanilla build exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Actually question is not only how it fails, but why... parsing the output of `date` seems like the most natural and simple use case for `date -d`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spent about two hours searching for this answer which has bugged me for years and I finally found it!!

By default `date` outputs a date in the current locale format such as `en_GB.UTF-8` or `en_AU.UTF-8` or `de_DE.UTF-8` etc

Your default locale looks like it is similar to mine and displays dates in the format:

`date_fmt    "%a %e %b %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"`

Unfortunately this is one of the few formats the date command can't understand. However, if **CAN understand** a very similar format

`date_fmt    "%a %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"`

"Fri 29 Jan 2016 22:04:26 GMT" Works

"Fri 29 Jan 22:04:26 GMT 2016" Doesn't

Why the very commonly used locale's en_GB.UTF-8 and en_AU.UTF-8 use a format that `date` can't read I don't know but it's very easy to tweak it so that it won't bother you again, at least not until you reinstall your system or your definitions get overwritten by an overzealous update >:-(

## How to customize your locale's date format in three steps

*I found the following information [here:](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale)*

#### 1. Check which locale you're using

First check which locale your system is using for it's time and date format

```
$ locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Note the **LC_TIME=** entry. Mine is English Australian: **en_AU.UTF-8** your's might be en_GB_UTF-8

#### 2. Edit the locale definition

Open a terminal and edit the appropriate locale definition

`$ sudo nano /usr/share/i18n/locales/{LC_Time}`

e.g.

```
$ sudo nano /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_AU
```

Scroll down to the LC_TIME section, here's mine:

```
LC_TIME
abday       "Sun";"Mon";"Tue";"Wed";"Thu";"Fri";"Sat"
day         "Sunday";/
            "Monday";/
            "Tuesday";/
            "Wednesday";/
            "Thursday";/
            "Friday";/
            "Saturday"
abmon       "Jan";"Feb";/
            "Mar";"Apr";/
            "May";"Jun";/
            "Jul";"Aug";/
            "Sep";"Oct";/
            "Nov";"Dec"
mon         "January";/
            "February";/
            "March";/
            "April";/
            "May";/
            "June";/
            "July";/
            "August";/
            "September";/
            "October";/
            "November";/
            "December"
d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"
d_fmt       "%d//%m//%y"
t_fmt       "%T"
am_pm       "AM";"PM"
t_fmt_ampm  "%I:%M:%S %p"
date_fmt    "%a %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
week 7;19971130;1
END LC_TIME
```

All you need to change is the `date_fmt` entry

I changed mine from:
`date_fmt    "%a %e %b %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"` to `date_fmt    "%a %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"`

Save the file and exit the editor

#### 3 Regenerate your locale

You recompile your locale definition files with:

```
$ sudo locale-gen
```

That's it! Now the `date` command should default to giving you output in a format that it can itself accept natively back as input

```
$ date -d "$(date)"
Mon 17 Aug 2020 17:58:37 AWST
```

Comment: P.S. If anyone wants to tell us how to make this locale change in a way that will never be overwritten by an upgrade please enlighten us :-)